# How to extract particular paragraph in text file using python?

Tags: python, string

I have to extract particular paragraphs starting from "SUBSTITUTION OF TRUSTEE" and ending with "under said Deed of Trust".

1. since the field is repeated need to find data only within paragraphs.
2. data might be like date, document num etc

```
sample.txt
Inst #: 2021
Fees: $42.00

06/24/2021 06:54:48 AM
Receipt #: 4587188

Requestor:
FINANCIAL CORPORATION OF
After recording return to: Src: MAIL

Mail Tax Statements to:

SUBSTITUTION OF TRUSTEE
AND DEED OF RECONVEYANCE

The undersigned, Financial Corporation of Nevada, a Nevada Corporation, as the Owner and
Holder of the Note secured by Deed of Trust dated March 1, 2013 made by Elvia Bello, Trustor, to
Official Records -- HEREBY substitutes Financial Corporation of Nevada, a Nevada Corporation,
as Trustee in lieu of the Trustee therein.


Said Note, together with all other indebtedness secured by said Deed of Trust, has been fully paid 
satisfied; and as successor Trustee, the undersigned does hereby RECONVEY WITHOUT
WARRANTY TO THE PERSON OR PERSONS LEGALLY ENTITLED THERETO, all the estate now
held by it under said Deed of Trust.
This JNO aay of June 2021,
Financial Corporation
wy luo Rtn rae
```

```
import re
mylines = []

pattern = re.compile(r"SUBSTITUTION OF TRUSTEE", re.IGNORECASE)
with open(r'sample.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:                 
            mylines.append(line)
    for line in mylines:
        if(line == "SUBSTITUTION OF TRUSTEE "):
            print(line)
            break
        else:
            mylines.remove(line)
    
    print("my lines",mylines)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check each line for the `substitution of trustee` substring at its start first, and once found, set a flag variable to *True*. When the flag is true, keep adding lines to the `mylines` list. Then, once you get to the line containing `under said deed or trust`, stop adding lines and return the result:

```py
mylines = []
flag = False
with open(r'sample.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if line.strip().upper().startswith("SUBSTITUTION OF TRUSTEE"):
            flag = not flag
        if flag:
            mylines.append(line)
            if "under said deed of trust" in line.strip().lower():
                break

print("".join(mylines))
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZOHbVi).

Output:

```
SUBSTITUTION OF TRUSTEE
AND DEED OF RECONVEYANCE

The undersigned, Financial Corporation of Nevada, a Nevada Corporation, as the Owner and
Holder of the Note secured by Deed of Trust dated March 1, 2013 made by Elvia Bello, Trustor, to
Official Records -- HEREBY substitutes Financial Corporation of Nevada, a Nevada Corporation,
as Trustee in lieu of the Trustee therein.


Said Note, together with all other indebtedness secured by said Deed of Trust, has been fully paid 
satisfied; and as successor Trustee, the undersigned does hereby RECONVEY WITHOUT
WARRANTY TO THE PERSON OR PERSONS LEGALLY ENTITLED THERETO, all the estate now
held by it under said Deed of Trust.
```

Comment: @wintor stibizew,  if I need to pass a list of elements in startswith()?

Comment: @Sand Then use `if re.match("|".join(map(re.escape, list_of_words)), line.strip(), flags=re.I):`

Comment: if any(line.strip().upper().startswith(str(title)) for title in title_start):
     flag = not flag

Comment: @Sand Ok, that is a bit longer to write, I was in the metro using my mobile phone when I was writing the above comment :) Also, I don't think you need `str(title)`, just `title` should do, or get the string property of `title` if it is some object.

Comment: that's correct,  how can stop the loop when I have multiple ending elements like ["under said deed of trust", "referred to herein"]

Comment: @Sand Maybe `if any(line.strip().upper().endswith(title) for title in title_end)`?

Comment: no that will not work, not all lines end with these words. if I found [title_end] in the middle of the line should break the loop.  text files each line must find the end word. where end words are not constant.

Comment: @Sand then check if they are `in` the string, `if any(title in line.strip().upper() for title in title_end)`

Comment: that is solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naïve method to accomplish what you intend -

```
extracted_lines=[]
extract = False

for line in open("sample.txt"):

    if extract == False and "SUBSTITUTION OF TRUSTEE".lower() in line.strip().lower():
        extract = True
        
    if extract :
        extracted_lines.append(line)
        if "under said Deed of Trust".lower() in line.strip().lower():
            extract = False # or break
            
print("".join(extracted_lines))
```